# How to fix "OSError: [Errno -9986] Internal PortAudio error" with speech_recognition module on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, speech-to-text, pyaudio

I was trying to build a speech-to-text recognition with python on macOS (please do not post suggestions for Windows devices here).

I'm trying to use the SpeechRecognition example code and developing my application, but every time I try to run the code I get the following error:

> **OSError: [Errno -9986] Internal PortAudio error**

I already have installed PortAudio with
`brew install portaudio` and PyAudio as well with
`pip3 install pyaudio`.

Here is the example code:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
try:
    # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

This is the traceback of the error message:

```
||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| Error on line 1277: err='-66748', msg=Unknown Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a97bf104167b> in <module>
      3 # obtain audio from the microphone
      4 r = sr.Recognizer()
----> 5 with sr.Microphone() as source:
      6     print("Say something!")
      7     audio = r.listen(source)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py in __enter__(self)
    136         try:
    137             self.stream = Microphone.MicrophoneStream(
--> 138                 self.audio.open(
    139                     input_device_index=self.device_index, channels=1,
    140                     format=self.format, rate=self.SAMPLE_RATE, frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK,

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py in open(self, *args, **kwargs)
    748         """
    749 
--> 750         stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
    751         self._streams.add(stream)
    752         return stream

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py in __init__(self, PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input, output, input_device_index, output_device_index, frames_per_buffer, start, input_host_api_specific_stream_info, output_host_api_specific_stream_info, stream_callback)
    439 
    440         # calling pa.open returns a stream object
--> 441         self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
    442 
    443         self._input_latency = self._stream.inputLatency

OSError: [Errno -9986] Internal PortAudio error
```

Comment: @GinoMempin Just added the trackback to the post. Let me know if you have any cooments.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. brew uninstall portaudio
2. brew install portaudio --HEAD

This worked for me. I got it from this Github issue: https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/299